# Blazor adds Random html attributes and breaks style

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, blazor

I Have a simple UI with a simple navigation bar
(like the example stuff you get with a new net core 5 Blazor Server Project)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark p-0">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">
          <span class="oi oi-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> Test
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="test2">
          <span class="oi oi-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Test2
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <LoginDisplay />
  </div>
</nav>
```

When i start the app and debug it with e.g. Firefox(F12) however it looks like this.
It adds those `b-70pbkjl90q=""` elements that break style

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark p-0" b-70pbkjl90q="">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" b-70pbkjl90q="">
    <!--!-->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" b-70pbkjl90q="">
      <li class="nav-item px-3" b-70pbkjl90q="">
        <a class="nav-link" href="" b-70pbkjl90q="">
          <span class="oi oi-list" aria-hidden="true" b-70pbkjl90q=""></span> Test
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3" b-70pbkjl90q="">
        <a class="nav-link" href="test2" b-70pbkjl90q="">
          <span class="oi oi-cog" aria-hidden="true" b-70pbkjl90q=""></span> Test2
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It looks like that.
[image]

But it should look like this
[image]

How can i get rid of theese?

Comment: Hi @Mr.Pearce, can you clarify more about this attribute `b-70pbkjl90q`? is it just a custom attribute?

Comment: Hi @FeiHan that's literally the point. I Don't know where it comes from. First code is my source. Second is from browser Debugger Window when the app runs.(Edited the original to clarify)
I don't even know where i could set such attributes.

Comment: I have exactly same problem but with a classic razor page (no blazor), any idea? The solution with option DisableScopedCssBundling doesn't work.
The problem is only on the layout page...

Comment: Finally i found the option for Razor page, in the project .csproj add the property:
  <PropertyGroup>
   <ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're using `ComponentName.razor.css`.

I had the same issue after I removed the css file and it started to work.

Comment: Yes. I think actually it was the ComponentName.razor.css i didnt even see.
Found it much later in the process.

Answer (score 0):

After some deeper digging i found that blazer creates some per component css file that brakes my stuff.

You can disable this behavior by adding this to your .csproj

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DisableScopedCssBundling>true</DisableScopedCssBundling>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: For Razor pages the option is different:
  <PropertyGroup>
   <ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>